# How to implement "Linphone" in Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, linphone

I have created an Android Application in that I want to implement "Linphone" for voice and video call.

I had download Library project from https://github.com/viv/linphone-android but missing some files in that library.

Can you give me some instruction for getting missing files in Windows OS for Eclipse.

So please provide me some links of complete library code and sample example.

Thanks.

Comment: please read the readme section in the link it completely guides you to the end and it is better to use android studio now as google has finished the support from eclipse ... :)

Comment: @Darkie, I checked the README file, but how to setup in Windows.